# Switch out faces in videos

Tags: video-editor

I was wondering if there is any open source software that I can use to easily add images to a video, track the faces, and replace them like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cWkiKaRHDE) video?

Comment: see http://filmora.wondershare.com/video-editor/free-linux-video-editor.html for a list.

Comment: @Rinzwind [Wondershare is a known forum spammer and violator of the GPL](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3988).